# Proposition 3 in Chapter I.7 (Dimension) of Mumford's Red Book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In Mumford's Red book, chapter I.7 (Dimension), the proof of Proposition 3 (1.) has the step:

> If $B=f^{\star -1}(A)$, apply the going-up theorem to $S/B\subset R/A$.

What does the inclusion means and how does it relate to the condition of going-up theorem ??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

$f^* : S \to R$ is a finite ring homomorphism and $A$ is an ideal of $R$. Hence, $B:=(f^*)^{-1}(A)$ is an ideal if $S$, and $f^*$ induces an injective finite ring homomorphism $S/B \to R/A$ (given by $[s] \mapsto [f(s)]$). Going-up implies that an injective integral (for example finite) homomorphism is surjective on prime spectra. Applying this to $S/B \hookrightarrow R/A$, we get that $f : V(A) \to V(B)$ is surjective. And this is what Mumford needs in his proof.